# Making new rails shortcuts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm new to rails and have only really had to use "**rails s**" to start up the server.  Now that I'm getting into processes and things like Foreman gem.  that has evolved to "**foreman start**".  With heroku, I need to have multiple procfile's and now i'm doing "**foreman start -f procfile.dev**"

**Is there a standard "rails way" to make application specific shortcuts, or alter what "rails s" points to for a given app**?

Should I just be using Rake? Or normal terminal scripts?

I want to ask before i develop any bad habits.  Thx!

Comment: I don't know what the 'rails way' would be, but I would just make some terminal scripts or a bash alias for a shortcut.

Comment: i found this, https://github.com/aziz/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/aliases/rails.aliases.bash.  Was hoping for a portable solution though so if  checkout somewhere else i still have the aliases